# Creating PHP TCO Calculator

Tags: php, forms

I am creating a TCO Calculator. I am able to get the first part of the PHP that displays the preset numbers in the input fields and calculates the variables into a final result just fine. The second part, where the user can change the numbers in those inputs and then recalculate the results in the same page isn't working. Here is what I've got done so far:

```
    <?php

        // This works like a charm!

        // prefill the form inputs
        $parnum = "1000000000"; // Revenues
        $pirnum = "4.00"; // % Revenue
        $pesnum = "10.00"; // % Scope

        // calculate the form formula
        $hccput = round($parnum * ($pirnum / 100) * ($pesnum / 100));
        $hcprice_text = (string)$hccput; // convert into a string
        $tothccost = number_format($hcprice_text);
        $preput = $hccput;
        $preput2 = .535808;
        $eqdput = round($preput * $preput2);
        $eqdprice_text = (string)$eqdput; // convert into a string
        $toteqdhccost = number_format($eqdprice_text);

        // create the dynamic bars
        $toteqdhcsave = round(100 - ($eqdput / $preput) * 100);
        $toteqdhcsave2 = 100 - $toteqdhcsave;
        $eqdhcsoutput = $toteqdhcsave2;
        $tothcsave = 100;
        $toteqdhcper = 'height:' . $toteqdhcsave . '%';
        $tothcper = 'height:' . $tothcsave . '%';
    ?>

    <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <form id="hard-cost" class="medium-6 columns clearfix" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                    <h2 class="text-center">(PHP)</h2>
                    <div class="slidecontainer">
                            <div class="small-12 columns">
                                    <label>Revenues</label>
                                    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $parnum; ?>" onchange="handleChange10(this);" min="1" max="10000000000" name="parnumphp" id="parnumphp" />
                                    <label>% Revenue</label>
                                    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $pirnum; ?>" onchange="handleChange11(this);" min="1.00" max="100.00" name="pirnumphp" id="pirnumphp" />
                                    <label>% Scope</label>
                                    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $pesnum; ?>" onchange="handleChange11(this);" min="1.00" max="100.00" name="pesnumphp" id="pesnumphp" />
                                    <input type="button" value="submit" class="button blue-bg white m-bottom" name="hchnumphp" id="hchnumphp" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
            <div class="tothc-calcphp medium-6 columns medium-centered">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Pay <span id="toteqdhcsave"><?php echo $toteqdhcsave2; ?></span>% less</h4>
                    <ul id="bars">
                            <li class="small-4 small-push-1 columns">
                                    <div id="toteqdhcper" class="bar" style="<?php echo $toteqdhcper; ?>"></div>
                                    <div class="bar-text">
                                            <h4>Cost 1:<br /> $<span id="toteqdhccost"><?php echo $toteqdhccost; ?></span></h4>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="small-4 small-push-3 columns">
                                    <div id="tothcper" class="bar" style="<?php echo $tothcper; ?>"></div>

                                    <div class="bar-text">
                                            <h4>Cost 2:<br /> $<span id="tothccost"><?php echo $tothccost; ?></span></h4>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
    </div>

    <?php

        // THIS ISN'T WORKING AT ALL!!!
        if(isset($_POST['hchnumphp'])){
            $parnumphp = $_POST["parnumphp"]; // Revenue
            $pirnumphp = $_POST["pirnumphp"]; // % Revenue
            $pesnumphp = $_POST["pesnumphp"]; // % Scope

            echo "parnumphp is: " . $parnumphp; // TESTING BUT IT"S NOT WORKING
            echo "pirnumphp is: " . $pirnumphp; // TESTING BUT IT"S NOT WORKING
            echo "pesnumphp is: " . $pesnumphp; // TESTING BUT IT"S NOT WORKING

            // calculate the formula
            $hccputphp = round($parnumphp * ($pirnumphp / 100) * ($pesnumphp / 100));
            $hcprice_textphp = (string)$hccputphp; // convert into a string
            $tothccostphp = number_format($hcprice_textphp); 
            $preputphp = $hccputphp;
            $preput2php = .535808;
            $eqdputphp = round($preputphp * $preput2php);
            $eqdprice_textphp = (string)$eqdputphp; // convert into a string
            $toteqdhccostphp = number_format($eqdprice_textphp);

            // create the dynamic bars
            $toteqdhcsavephp = round(100 - ($eqdputphp / $preputphp) * 100);
            $toteqdhcsave2php = 100 - $toteqdhcsavephp;
            $eqdhcsoutputphp = $toteqdhcsave2php;
            $tothcsavephp = 100;
            $toteqdhcperphp = 'height:' . $toteqdhcsavephp . '%';
            $tothcperphp = 'height:' . $tothcsavephp . '%';
        }

    ?>

    <script>
            function handleChange10(input) {
                    if (input.value < 1) input.value = 1;
                    if (input.value > 10000000000) input.value = 10000000000;
            }
            function handleChange11(input) {
                    if (input.value < 1) input.value = 1;
                    if (input.value > 100) input.value = 100;
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why would you put the non-working part where it is?  I suspect you have a misunderstanding about server-client operations.  At any rate, typical usage is to create your script so that it goes in the following order:  1) Initialize, 2) Act on user input, 3) perform any remaining logic, 4) output the results.

Comment: What is the output from `echo "parnumphp is: "` lines?

Comment: Alex, there is no output. Nothing gets echoed out.

Comment: Tim, Can you recommend an online class or perhaps book that would help a beginner with PHP for learning the concepts you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get notified about your comment.  Off the top of my head, I don't know of a tutorial; I picked up the concept initially from a project called phplib about 20 years ago...  I started an answer for you and then got busy with work.  If that would still be helpful, let me know and I'll get back to it.